# querying mongodb using pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

i just started using mongodb and setup a test database to handle web scraping results from a couple scripts i created. right now, the date_found is being loaded as a string. when i run this in mongohub:

```
{"date_found" : /.*2015-05-02.*/}
```

i get all the collections with '2015-05-02'. awesome!

however, when i run:

```
for item in collection.find({"date_found": "/.*2015-05-02.*/"}):
    print item
```

i get nothing.

also, this:

```
for item in collection.find():
    print item
```

gives me all the collections, so it seems everything works to the extent that i can query the database.

any chance someone can tell me what bonehead mistake i'm making (or what i'm missing)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pymongo, to include a **[regular expression](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html)** you could try something like this:

```
import re
regx = re.compile(".*2015-05-02.*")
for item in collection.find({"date_found": regx})
    print item
```

Or using the [**`$regex`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) operator:

```
import re
regx = re.compile(".*2015-05-02.*")
for item in collection.find({"date_found": {"$regex": regx} })
    print item
```

Comment: both of those are throwing an "sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat" at the regx line...

Comment: Looks like the leading `.` is missing in those regex strings.

Comment: I have updated the answer the include the leading `.`. Thanks to @JohnnyHK for the heads-up.

Comment: works like a charm. do you mind shedding some light on the difference? i'm assuming it has something to do with pymongo but i'm not really sure...just trying to understand. thanks again!

Comment: Basically the leading `.` matches any char except newline, best explained by this [**Python 2.7 Regular Expressions Cheat Sheet**](https://github.com/tartley/python-regex-cheatsheet/blob/master/cheatsheet.rst).

Comment: gotcha. i was talking more about the difference between query mongoldb directly and/or using pymongo.